# The wcf service loses the logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, winapi

I have an issue with WCF sessions and log files.
WCF is hosted in a Windows services and serves requests from a ASP.NET web application. Each user connect has its own session "in memory" and has a sessions id. Each session initialize a new log class and write logs in different folder for each user. It happens that after some time the file keep growth and date time updated but the rows are not present in the file. 
I suspect that the buffering of file system or framework doesn't write all rows so I changed to CreateFile Win32 API with NO_BUFFERING options.

```
SafeFileHandle hcFile = Win32API.CreateFile(@"C:\Temp\File.log", System.IO.FileAccess.Write,
                System.IO.FileShare.Read, IntPtr.Zero,
                System.IO.FileMode.Append,
                (System.IO.FileAttributes)Win32API.FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (!hcFile.IsInvalid) {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(hcFile, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.WriteLine("Log row log row log row");
            sw.WriteLine("Log row log row log row");
            sw.WriteLine("Log row log row log row");
        }
```

But the handle is always NOT VALID?
Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: If the call fails use `GetLastError` to get detailed information about the specific error. (See the MSDN documentation for `CreateFile`.) But even so, if you open the file with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` you must write an entire sector, which could be as large as 4096 bytes. All of that said, I doubt that buffering is the problem, since thousands of people are doing the same thing without issue. Have you verified that your logging process is actually attempting to write to the log? Are you properly closing files when you're done with them? Is something else in your program leaking handles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you using the win32?  You can use the File object just as easily.

```
var logFile = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Append);
```

or since you have all your text lines just put then in an array and write all at once.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filePath,new string[] { "Line 1", "Line 2" , "Line 3"});
```

One note... if you are writing this via WCF web service, keep in mind that the account the web service is running under will need write permissions to the directory.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try that.
For the WCF that stop to write log? Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: I apologize Kevbo for my imprecision. It seesm that after some time of correct working, the library in the WCF file don't write the row of text to the log file. The size on disk increase but the log is not present.

Comment: I would check the path of where it is saving it and also check the permissions on the folder.  Its possible that updates from windows update can affect these things.  I have written many log files for apps and permissions is usually the problem.

Comment: One step forward... We discovered that suddenly the streamwriter is null! Maybe that if the wcf is idle unload dll? There is a way to detect when and who set the streamwriter to null?

Comment: You should be opening and closing the stream each time you write to it.  Dont leave the stream open.  You should open the stream,  then write what you need, then close it.  If you want to buffer a bunch of lines and then write it all at once at the end of the process then you should be saving all the data and then do the writing at the end.  I have written a nice little log class that can do this for you.  I can provide the code if you are interested.

Comment: I should mention one more thing about this issue.  WCF calls can happen simultaneously so you may be running into locking issues with multiple threads trying to write to the same file at the same time.  This means you need to be aware of how long you hold a file open when writing.  If you open the file at the begining of a process and then close it at the end you are increasing the chances of a file lock happening.  Best practice is to build a string along the way and then write to the file once at the very end so its only locked for a brief moment.